# Geometry Textbook Suggestions

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

Please suggest me a book for plane and solid geometry. I tried finding a book specifically for the geometry of inmo exam but didnt find anything.

Comment: I assume "inmo" is the Indian National Mathematics Olympiad?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: There are many different kinds of books on plane and solid geometry.  I suspect that only those with familiarity with that exam can know what sort of book you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about I in INMO, but growing up (MANY  years ago) in the Olympiad gangs in my home country, Hadamard (both volumes, plane and solid geometry) was far and away the best prep for geometry. I don't think that has changed.

https://education.ti.com/en/us/publishers/pubconnect_ams2/hadamards-lessons-in-geometry-i-plane-geometry

Comment: It is indian national math Olympiad

Comment: I got that, I can read. What I meant was, I don't know what is special about "Indian" math Olympiad, vs. other countries. Thanks!